# Python script to control mouse clicks

Tags: python, keyboard, tkinter, mouseevent, pywin32

I created a small Python script using win32api to use on the popular game [Cookie Clicker](http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/) (a game where you have to click on a Big Cookie to gain points) just for fun. It has a function called "auto_clicker" that do just that: keeps clicking on the screen on the point the user defined. This is the script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import win32con
import win32api

def clicker(x,y):
    """Clicks on given position x,y

    Input:
    x -- Horizontal position in pixels, starts from top-left position
    y -- Vertical position in pixels, start from top-left position

    """

    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)

def auto_clicker(x = -1,y = -1):
    """Keep clicking on position x,y. If no input is given, gets from actual
    mouse position.

    """
    if x == -1 | y == -1:
        x,y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    while True:
        clicker(x,y)
```

It works nicely, but I want to make some improvements:

- How can I get the cursor position only when the user clicks instead when the function is called? I would prefer to not add another module
  since win32api seems to contain everything I needed. Tried [this](http://pythonsnips.blogspot.com.br/2011/01/mouse-click.html)
  method without success.
- How can I detect a keypress like "Escape", so I can exit from my program without the ugly hack I am using now (Ctrl+Alt+Del seems to give SetCursorPos denied access, so Python throws a error and exit the program).
- Can I make this program portable? Seems like I can do using Tkinter and generating a invisible Tk window, but I tried to write something without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think with win32api you can listen to clicks you can just generate them (not sure though). However, try using pyHook, it's a simple api easy to use and can be found here http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyhook/index.php?title=Main_Page. With pyhook you can create a listener to listen to a mouse event and upon a mouse click you can do whatever you want, the example in the link shows you how. As for key press, you can use the same api for that too, also an example is provided, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

use pynput . It can control mouse, keyboard, etc.

examples:

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

mouse = Controller()

# Read pointer position
print('The current pointer position is {0}'.format(
    mouse.position))

# Set pointer position
mouse.position = (10, 20)
print('Now we have moved it to {0}'.format(
    mouse.position))

# Move pointer relative to current position
mouse.move(5, -5)

# Press and release
mouse.press(Button.left)
mouse.release(Button.left)

# Double click; this is different from pressing and releasing
# twice on Mac OSX
mouse.click(Button.left, 2)

# Scroll two steps down
mouse.scroll(0, 2)
```